# How to automatically reload the data from viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to find the solution for how to automatically reload all the data in view controller but i can't find any. Right now i am using push to refresh to reload the button/title/data in view controller `viewDidload()` but i want to have it automalliy reload everything every time i come back to this viewcontroller. For example when app lunched, it load view controller A then i clicked on the button to go View controller B but i want to controller A to refresh everything after back from B so how can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Insert the refresh methods into the viewWillAppear,  it gets called every time the view appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, there is a method [`viewWillAppear`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear)

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    reloadData()
}

func reloadData() {
    //All you need to update
}
```